# ios simulator orientation wrong on second

Tags: ios, simulator

I have created a small app with just three views. I have only selected LandscapeRight orientation. in the iOS simulator only the first view shows up in landscape. The other views are in portrait. I can rotate the simulator, but the storyboard layout rotates with it and does not display correct.
the info.plist file has only the (Landscapre Right) orientation item.

Kind regards 
Teddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what Wilhelmsen had said, It is annoying but you must add the following code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```

However, I would also like to add that you MUST ADD THIS INTO EACH SEPARATE VIEW CONTROLLER in order for it to rotate for the other view as well.

For instance, lets say I have viewcontroller_1 and viewcontroller_2, I have to go into both .m files of the controller and add the following code. If you dont, it may not rotate for one of the views.

Comment: Thanks. I had added the other view controllers as sub views to the initial view controllers, so they didn´t have their own

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is annoying, but add this to your .m file and it works

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

return (toInterfaceOrientation ==      UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```